# How to use custom helper method's return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods

I have a method in application_helper:

```
def methodname(argument)
 if "XXXX".match(/#{argument}/i).present?
 puts "YYYY"
else
end
```

And in console:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/application_helper"
=> true
include ApplicationHelper
=> Object
> methodname("argument")
YYYY=> nil
> loremipsum = methodname("argument")
YYYY=> nil
> loremipsum
=> nil
```

So it returns YYYY which is correct but it also returns nil for some reason beyond my understanding. I only need YYYY. How can I "extract" / use it? I would like:

```
> somemagicalcommand
> "YYYY"
```

:)

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `puts` function, which outputs something on the console, like a `printf` on C, or `System.out.printf` in Java.

If instead of using `puts` you return the value, I think you may have the result you're looking for :).

`def methodname(argument)
 return "YYYY" if "XXXX".match(/#{argument}/i).present?
end`